# Pandas groupby.rank by absolute value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have some DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange'], 'columnB': [0.10, -0.15, 0.25, 0.50, -0.51, 0.70]})


columnA columnB
0   apple   0.10
1   apple   -0.15
2   apple   0.25
3   orange  0.50
4   orange  -0.51
5   orange  0.70
```

I am trying to rank each group member in `columnA` by the absolute value of `columnB`.

```
df['rank'] = df.reindex(df['columnB'].abs().sort_values(ascending=False).index).groupby('columnA')['columnB'].rank(ascending=False)


columnA columnB rank
0   apple   0.10    2.0
1   apple   -0.15   3.0
2   apple   0.25    1.0
3   orange  0.50    2.0
4   orange  -0.51   3.0
5   orange  0.70    1.0
```

But the rankings above are not by absolute value as I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, using `pandas.Series.abs`:

```
df['rank'] = df['columnB'].abs().groupby(df['columnA']).rank(ascending=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  columnA  columnB  rank
0   apple     0.10   3.0
1   apple    -0.15   2.0
2   apple     0.25   1.0
3  orange     0.50   3.0
4  orange    -0.51   2.0
5  orange     0.70   1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat one liner to get you the desired outcome:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('columnA',as_index=False)['columnB'].apply(lambda s: s.abs().rank(ascending=False)).values
```

Note, `abs` cannot be applied directly on a groupby object, rather, only on a series or dataframe. The `lambda` method here allows you to compute the `abs` directly on the `group_df` of the desired range to be sorted.